# Could use some clarification on arm architecture settings in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, arm, ios6

From what I've read, the iPhone 5 will use a new architecture, `armv7s`. My project had valid architectures as `armv7`, and had `Build Active Architecture Only` set to `true`. Since every app in the store right now is built for `armv6` and/or `armv7`, I can't imagine that it will not run on the new iPhone. So what occurs? Does it just not run as well as it could?

I could just use a better explanation of what is occurring, and what would be different once I rebuild and submit with `armv7s` as a valid architecture.

Comment: There's something to add to that: armv6 arch has already been deprecated by Apple, have a look: [link](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/08/softly-killing-iphone-3g/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it's **armv7**, not arm7 (yes, there is a difference). I can't seem to find any docs on the specifics, but I imagine armv7s adds support for some optional ARMv7 features, e.g. VFPv4/FMA, or UDIV/SDIV integer division instructions. I can't imagine the difference will be noticeable unless your app deals with a lot of math or graphics.

**Edit**: see [this link](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/eb1641d54a7eda7717304bc4d55d059208d8ebed) for the changes made to LLVM for armv7s support. From what I see, it's indeed just VFPv4 and integer divide, plus some changes to the instruction scheduler. Apparently the CPU codename is "Swift".

Comment: Anand Lal Shimpi seems to confirm the use of VFPv4 for ARMv7s: http://www.anandtech.com/show/6292/iphone-5-a6-not-a15-custom-core